Print input element even when capture() fails to match expression
I'm trying to extract info on certain specific dependencies from the output of DTrack's /v1/project endpoint.
The API returns data in the format:
[{
    "name": "project name",
    "classifier": "LIBRARY | APPLICATION",
    "directDependencies": <escaped JSON string in which I need to search for "com.example.commons/dep1@0.101.0" and similar strings>
}, ...]

Here's what I got so far:
jq '.[] | select(.classifier=="APPLICATION") | {
      id: .name,
      dep1: ((.directDependencies // "") | capture(["com\\.example\\.commons/dep1@(?<version>[0-9.]+)"])),
      dep2: ((.directDependencies // "") | capture(["com\\.example\\.commons/dep2@(?<version>[0-9.]+)"])),
      dep3: ((.directDependencies // "") | capture(["com\\.example\\.commons/dep3@(?<version>[0-9.]+)"])),
      dep4: ((.directDependencies // "") | capture(["com\\.example\\.commons/dep4@(?<version>[0-9.]+)"]))
    }'

Generated output looks fine:
{
  "id": "project1",
  "dep1": {
    "version": "0.102.0"
  },
  "dep2": {
    "version": "0.102.0"
  },
  "dep3": {
    "version": "0.102.0"
  },
  "dep4": {
    "version": "0.102.0"
  }
}
... // more elements

The problem is, the output only contains those of the input elements for which all four captures matched something.
I would like the output to contain all the elements of the input list, even if some of the captures fail to match. In other words, I would expect elements in the output like:
{
    "id": "project1",
    "dep1": { "version": "0.1.0" },
    // dep2 didn't match
    // dep3 didn't match
    "dep4": { "version": "0.3.0" }
}

I couldn't find such an option in the docs. Any ideas how to solve this?

@0stone0 the last paragraph of my question literally says 'I would expect elements in the output like', followed by an example. What else would you have me include?

@0stone0 I cannot post an actual example of the JSON, bc even the shortest one would not fit in the question character limit. What matters for the question is that the directDependencies is a string, which starts with useless junk, after which com.example.commons/dep1@0.100.0 appears, which is of interest for me, after which another bunch of useless junk starts again. If I just write "directDependencies": "xxxcom.example.commons/dep1@0.100.0yyy", instead, does that help?

What matters is that all four of dep1, dep2, dep3 and dep4 can appear in the string for some elements of the input array, only one or two may appear for others, and for some elements of the input array, directDependencies may contain none of the four

As I understand the question, you want to only add successful matches to the result object. I would prefer using scan to find all matches, and then reduce over them to successively build up the result object, while including the dependency name in the regex (e.g. as dep1|dep2|dep3|dep4, or shorter dep[1-4], or more generically [^@]+, which I've used below).
.[] | select(.classifier/" | " | any(. == "APPLICATION")) | reduce (
  .directDependencies | scan("com\\.example\\.commons/(?<dep>[^@]+)@(?<version>[0-9.]+)")
) as [$dep, $version] ({id: .name}; .[$dep] = {$version})

Note #1: This will always generate the {id: .name} part, even if no dependencies are added. To instead swallow these "naked" objects, start out the reduction with null, and filter eventually for non-null values:
.[] | select(.classifier/" | " | any(. == "APPLICATION")) | {id: .name} + (reduce (
  .directDependencies | scan("com\\.example\\.commons/(?<dep>[^@]+)@(?<version>[0-9.]+)")
) as [$dep, $version] (null; .[$dep] = {$version}) | values)

Note #2: Your filter select(.classifier=="APPLICATION") only matches objects where the value under .classifier is completely equal to the string "APPLICATION", and thus wouldn't catch your sample input at all as it contains {"classifier": "LIBRARY | APPLICATION"}. So instead, I used / to split that value at the substring " | ", and had it match if any (i.e. at least one) of the resulting parts was equal to that string.

Thanks a lot, it works! About the classifier, it's either APPLICATION or LIBRARY, I guess I didn't make that clear enough. As regards the "naked" objects, quite the opposite, the best solution for me would be to have an entry with absent values marked somehow, even if none of the four dependencies matched. Anyway, your suggestion will enable me to further refine the solution

@crizzis You can use something along the lines of values // {warning: "no dependencies"} to mark the "naked" items.

Will try that. BTW, if I wanted "dep1": "0.1.0" instead of "dep1": { "version": "0.1.0" } (so without the extra nested object), is there an easy way to accomplish that?

@crizzis Sure, change .[$dep] = {$version} to just .[$dep] = $version

Yeah, I just figured out it's gonna be simply referencing the variable value. I guess I need another coffee. Thanks a lot again!

You could use the approach exemplified by:
def capture($s; $default): capture($s) // $default;

.[]
| select(.classifier | test("APPLICATION"))
| {
      id: .name,
      dep1: ((.directDependencies // "") | capture(["com\\.example\\.commons/dep1@(?<version>[0-9.]+)"]; "dep1 did not match")),
      dep3: ((.directDependencies // "") | capture(["com\\.example\\.commons/dep3@(?<version>[0-9.]+)"]; "dep2 did not match")),
      dep4: ((.directDependencies // "") | capture(["com\\.example\\.commons/dep4@(?<version>[0-9.]+)"]; "dep1 did not match"))
  }



Thanks! This is the most elegant solution, I'm only accepting @pmf's answer bc it allows more flexibility
